# ActionBar Back Button StackTrace Error

Tags: android, navigation

With the help of these [Navigation with Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp).I try to create a Action Bar back button.

Back Button is displayed in output.But if I click the back button stacktrace error occurred at a time.

**StackTrace:**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846): Process: com.fth.android, PID: 1846
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity HomeActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:177)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(HomeActivity.java:160)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1846):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fth.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <application
        android:name="com.sit.fth.app.GemsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.YoutubePlayActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.fth.activity;

public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements
    VideoFragment.OnVideoSelectedListener,

    AboutFragment.OnAboutFragmentSelectedListener,

    AnnouncenentFragment.OnAnnouncementSelectedListener,

    GalleryFragment.OnGalItemSelectedListener,

    MagzineFragment.OnMagzineSelectedListener {
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);  // 160 th line Error
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected1(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {

            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I doesn't know how to solve these.Anybody can help me with these.Thank You.

Comment: Specify Parent activity name  **(android:parentActivityName)** in manifest.xml

Comment: @KaranMavadhiya I specified that Parent Activity name in manifest.check out my `<activity>` tag.

Comment: @Stephen did you do it for Home Activity? That is what stacktrace is telling you

Comment: @Raghunandan no I didn't add that in Home Activity.ok I will add that and tell you.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you.It is working now.you can post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity HomeActivity does not
>   have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the
>   android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY   element in your
>   manifest?)

You need mention the parent activity for Home Activity in manifest

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html